# Jquery Tabs using the list (li) tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

Can anyone tell me how I can use li tag instead of using the a href attribute to define the tabs in the javascript and html?

Any help would be appreciated

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />  
<script>  
$(function() {    
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();  
});  
</script>
</head>
<body> 


<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>   
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>    
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>  
  </ul>  
  <div id="tabs-1">    
  <p> hendrerit.</p>  
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">    
  <p> hendrerit.</p>  
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">    
  <p> hendrerit.</p>  
  </div>
  </div></div>  
  </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI Tabs API (that's a mouthful!) doesn't give you any options to modify the default  structure from above.

That being said, perhaps before calling `$.tabs()` you could use JavaScript to create the right  structure?

This example could be modified to whatever structure you have on your page, just use JS to rearrange and name items as necessary.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Tabs Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h2>Regular Tabs</h2>
<hr>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>Tabs Test</h2>
<hr>
<div id="tabs2">
  <ul>
    <li>Nunc tincidunt</li>
    <li>Proin dolor</li>
    <li>Aenean lacinia</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // regular html
    $('#tabs').tabs();

    // rewrite html
    var $tabs = $('#tabs2');
    var $liCount = $tabs.children('ul').children('li'); // count <li> children
    var $divCount = $tabs.children('div'); // count <div> children
    if($liCount.length == $divCount.length) { // no point in continuing if they don't match
        // lets create the html structure jquery ui needs
        var count = 0;
        $liCount.each(function(){
            count++;
            var html = '<a href="#tabs-' + count + '">' + $(this).html() + '</a>';
            $(this).html(html);
        });
        var count = 0;
        $divCount.each(function(){
            count++;
            $(this).attr('id', 'tabs-' + count);
        });

        // call tab()
        $('#tabs2').tabs();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This if i understood it right:

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />  
<script>  
$(function() {    
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();  
});  
</script>
</head>
<body> 


<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
  <li onclick="location.href='#tabs-1';"><a href="#">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>   
  <li onclick="location.href='#tabs-2';"><a href="#">Proin dolor</a></li>    
  <li onclick="location.href='#tabs-3';"><a href="#">Aenean lacinia</a></li>  
  </ul>  
  <div id="tabs-1">    
  <p> hendrerit.</p>  
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">    
  <p> hendrerit.</p>  
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">    
  <p> hendrerit.</p>  
  </div>
  </div></div>  
  </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to remove the  tags from the list items? I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. This is how I implement the vast majority of my navigation menus.

But, if you still would like to do this, there are multiple ways, of course. I'm not sure which is best. I'll propose one and let the community crush it if it's wrong. :)

You could do this:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li goto="tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And use jquery to handle the clicking of the tab:

```
$().ready({
    $('#tabs li').click(function() {
        var goto_id = $(this).attr('goto');
        var goto = $('#' + goto_id);
        $(window).scrollTop(goto.offset().top - $(window).offset().top + $(window).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Seems like overkill, though, considering all of this is built-in with the  tags